# Why can't my AMPL under Linux server find "gurobi"?

Tags: ampl, gurobi

I installed AMPL and Gurobi under Linux server, but when I tried to run a file with AMPL, an error message `Cannot find "gurobi"` occurred:

[image: here is the picture describing with the problem].

How can I deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the part "Note for Mac and Linux users" in this link:
http://myweb.clemson.edu/~pbelott/teaching/past-teaching/mthsc810-f11/mthsc810-ampl/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `gurobi` executable is not in the search paths specified by the `PATH` environment variable. There are multiple options:

- Add a symlink to `gurobi` from the directory on search paths such as `/usr/local/bin`.
- Modify `$PATH` to include directory containing `gurobi`.
- Specify the path to gurobi in the solver option, e.g.

  ```
  option solver `/path/to/gurobi`;
  ```

Comment: The path must use single or double quotes, not backquotes. `option solver '/path/to/gurobi';`